PDFTK and Evince Document Viewer bookmarks
Has something changed with Evince bookmarks so that pdftk doesn't recognize them? Document Viewer ver 46.0.
I created bookmarks in some_file.pdf with Evince Document Viewer, then ran
pdftk some_file.pdf dump_data output bookmarks.txt

but there were no bookmarks in the text file.
I created bookmarks in bookmarks.txt with the format:
  BookmarkBegin
  BookmarkTitle: Bookmark Title
  BookmarkLevel: 1
  BookmarkPageNumber: PageNumber

Loaded these to some_file_updated.pdf with
pdftk some_file.pdf update_info bookmarks.txt output some_file_updated.pdf

but my bookmarks appeared as an outline in Document Viewer, not bookmarks. I re-extracted my bookmarks from the updated PDF with pdftk and they were not in the output.
Is there something wrong with my bookmarks or is pdftk just not recognizing Evince bookmarks anymore?
